# Easiest web server setup up on AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

What is the simplest terraform file you can create to put Apache on and EC2 and give it a public IP on the internet?

I found this way works. But I'm wondering if there is something simpler.

```
# Network

resource "aws_vpc" "app_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.123.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.123.0.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public_rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_rt_asso" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_rt.id
}


# Security Group

resource "aws_security_group" "allow-http" {
  name        = "allow-http"
  description = "Allow incoming HTTP traffic"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  
  ingress {
    description      = "HTTP from VPC"
    from_port        = 80
    to_port          = 80
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}


# EC2

resource "aws_instance" "apache" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu_ami.id
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.allow-http.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  user_data = <<-EOF
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "*** Installing apache2"
  sudo apt update -y
  sudo apt install apache2 -y
  echo "*** Completed Installing apache2"
  EOF
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your Terraform config is already relatively simplistic. However, if you want to simplify further, you can look into some TF modules, such as [this AWS VPC Module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc) to simplify the creation of the VPC. You can also look into similar modules for [Security Groups](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-security-group) and [EC2 Instances](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance).

Your config is already relatively simple, so I wouldn't expect a huge reduction in your codebase. You are also introducing an external dependency on the module maintainer(s), which is something to consider. I would also consider [looking into different AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/usingsharedamis-finding.html) available on AWS - It might have something already available and configured with apache.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
# Network
resource "aws_vpc" "app_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.123.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.123.0.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
}

resource "aws_instance" "apache" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu_ami.id
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  user_data = <<-EOF
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "*** Installing apache2"
  sudo apt update -y
  sudo apt install apache2 -y
  echo "*** Completed Installing apache2"
  EOF
}
```

1. The Internet Gateway and Route Table have been removed as they are not necessary for a basic setup.
2. The VPC, Subnet, and EC2 instance setup remain to create a basic VPC, a public subnet, and launch an EC2 instance with Apache installed.

This configuration still accomplishes the goal of creating a VPC with a public subnet and an EC2 instance running Apache but is simplified by removing some of the additional components.

Answer (score 1):

Using terraform modules, you can easily deploy an EC2 machine with the least amount of codes:

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "5.1.2"

  name = "my-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs            = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b", "eu-west-1c"]
  public_subnets = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24", "10.0.103.0/24"]
}


module "ec2_instance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "5.5.0"

  name = "demo"

  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = module.vpc.public_subnets[0]
}
```

This way, not only your code becomes more readable, but you're also standing on the shoulders of giants before you, not reinventing the wheel, and most importantly, not accidentally introduce a bug or unintended behavior.